Is it possible to transform a simple linear row of data into complex row in microsoft Excel or?
I have a database with multiple columns. I want to shrink the width so that I can print it out. Example given below:
Name  Gender Age Weight Height BMI    Comments
Mr A  Male   41  50 Kg  1.5m   22.2   Long comment...
Mrs B Female 32  45     1.5m   20     Long comment...

Because the comment is long, I want to transform the data with multi-row in a single column like this
Name    Gender   Comment
        Age
        BMI

Mr A    Male     Comment - so the comment column has 3 rows and can have a longer width
        41         
        22.2

So basically the gender, age, and BMI are put in a single column with multiple rows. Thus the comment column can have a longer width.
Is it possible to transform the database like this?

What happened to Mrs B? Also it's unclear to me if you want to change the database, or you only want a different view of the data, but keep the database as is. Because as your data is now, before changing, is better usable for lookups, filters, or any analysis you plan to be doing. The new situation may appear better structured, but would be a hell to work with for retrieving any data from your database.

Also you dropped weight and height?

That is just an example. B will follow A. I have nearly a 1000 people. Row height has to be adjusted @P.b

Adjusted means dropped/omitted? (English is not my native language I read adjusted as "changed into something else")

bugdrown's solution is easier to understand. Thank you for your valuable time.

Try the following:
Insert a new column at B. In cell B2, enter
=C2&CHAR(10)&D2&CHAR(10)&G2

and copy it down the column. Format column B to Wrap Text.
Hide columns C:G.


Not truly as requested, but I figured you needed a visual presentation of the data, rather than it being a database, hence combining (joining) several values in a single cell rather than stacking cells, leaving empties.
=LET(data,A1:G3,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(data),3,LAMBDA(r,c,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,INDEX(data,r,CHOOSE(c,1,{2,3,4},7))))))
Make sure you enable text wrap to let the different values show stacked within the cells:


Thank you for your answer. @bugdrown's answer is simpler and easier to understand.
